# How can I find identical tables in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is there an easy way to find identical tables, i.e. same structure and data, using MySQL and PHP? I doubt there is a MySQL command for it, but how would you recommend doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more information about the structure or size of your data, you could do this:

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) AND COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2),1,0) AS result FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM table2
) tables_joined
```

But be warned, it's not an ideal solution. For large datasets, it could take a while

This is untested, but the general premise of the answer is:

- Join the two tables. If the structure is consistent (at a basic level - this does not include data types, indexes etc) then you won't get any errors
- After the join, compare the number of rows to the number of rows in one of the tables
- If the number of rows are equal, then the data is identical (because otherwise the join would have returned two rows).
- Output 1 if identical or 0 if not.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it doesn't seem to be working. With identical table structures, the expression returns `1` even when one table has one row and the other has two.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Indeed, if the count was the same as table 1, it didn't mean the count was the same as table 2. I've updated the IF statement accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Identical tables MUST have identical ids, so you just need to check if there is any difference between ids in both tables, so the following code should be helpful:

```
Select count(*) from table1 where table1_id IN (select table2_id from table2);
```

if result is 0, then there is difference.

The better way is seeing and checking the table structure, like (imagine we got 2 tables named orod1 and orod2):

```
select table_name,column_name,data_type 
from information_schema.columns where table_schema='orod_schema' and table_name ='orod%';
```

Comment: IDs can be identical but the data in the rest of the row could be completely different. All this will confirm is that the number of rows is the same. I like your idea for confirming identical structure though.